# A theorem style with only a parenthesized number label

Tags: amsthm

I am looking to create a theorem-like environment using the AMS LaTeX system which consists of just a parenthesized number: no other declaration like theorem, lemma, etc. Other properties (spacing above and below the environment, space between the number and the start of text, etc.) should be the same as the ordinary theorem-like environments.

My big idea was to use the `\newtheoremstyle` command with `\newtheorem` as follows, found within a minimal non-working example:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{amsbook}
\usepackage{amsthm}

\newtheoremstyle{parens}
  {.5\baselineskip±.2\baselineskip}
  {.5\baselineskip±.2\baselineskip}
  {}
  {\parindent}
  {}
  {)}
  {.5em}
  {}
  {}
\theoremstyle{parens}
\newtheorem{nitem}[equation]{(} %(*)

\begin{document}

\begin{nitem}
   This is a test of the emergency broadcasting system.
\end{nitem}

(1)\hspace*{.5em}This is a test of the emergency broadcasting system.
\end{document}
```

This is the result:
[image: image showing error in desired theorem style]
So the number is surrounded by parens as desired, but there is that annoying space after the left-hand parenthesis. I suspect that `newtheoremstyle` was not intended to be used in this way... But: can the space be eliminated in some general way? My temporary solution has been to introduce a negative space after the ( in the line marked (*), but I don't know what sort of space would do the correction over all typefaces and type sizes. Or is there another way? Thanks for reading this.

Comment: Will you need to be able to create cross-references to some of the theorem-like entries? Will they be numbered consecutively?

Comment: Yes, and yes. I used the equation counter to number everything consecutively, including equations, and theorems, and cross-referencing is desired.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the last argument (head-spec) of `\newtheoremstyle` (note that you have one `{}` too many).

```
\documentclass[11pt]{amsbook}
\usepackage{amsthm}

\newtheoremstyle{parens}
  {.5\baselineskip plus .2\baselineskip minus .2\baselineskip}
  {.5\baselineskip plus .2\baselineskip minus .2\baselineskip}
  {}
  {\parindent}
  {}
  {}
  {.5em}
  {(\thmnumber{#2})\thmnote{ [#3]}}

\theoremstyle{parens}
\newtheorem{nitem}[equation]{}

\begin{document}

\begin{nitem}
   This is a test of the emergency broadcasting system.
\end{nitem}

(1)\hspace*{.5em}This is a test of the emergency broadcasting system.

\begin{nitem}[Something]
   This is a test of the emergency broadcasting system.
\end{nitem}

\end{document}
```

I used brackets for the theorem note (but you probably don't have them).

[image]

You cannot specify rubber lengths with `±`. You get no error, but a couple of warnings

```
(\end occurred when \ifx on line 14 was incomplete)
(\end occurred when \ifx on line 14 was incomplete)
```

for each call of `nitem` and the glue specification is not flexible.

Comment: Oooh, he is here! Question: is there an issue with my answer, adding the \ignorespaces? In the sense that the resulting spacing might not be exactly what is should be?

Comment: @olso-n-so Your way works, but it's a hack.

Comment: Fair enough, 'though much of my LaTeX work is just that. Never could figure what the head spec line does, so this gives me something to study. Which I will now do. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

(edited at the request of Mensch) So maybe posting here clarifies the mind. I can solve the problem and make the `\newtheorem` work as desired by simply adding an `\ignorespaces` to that line, which is labelled (*):

```
\documentclass[11pt]{amsbook}
\usepackage{amsthm}

\newtheoremstyle{parens}
  {.5\baselineskip±.2\baselineskip}
  {.5\baselineskip±.2\baselineskip}
  {}
  {\parindent}
  {}
  {)}
  {.5em}
  {}
  {}
\theoremstyle{parens}
\newtheorem{nitem}[equation]{(\ignorespaces} %(*)

\begin{document}

\begin{nitem}
   This is a test of the emergency broadcasting system.
\end{nitem}

(1)\hspace*{.5em}This is a test of the emergency broadcasting system.
\end{document}
```

Comment: Please -- as usual here -- show a short compilable TeX code for your solution for a fast proof ...

Comment: Apologies: I thought that it would be clear that the line would be inserted in the original code in the question, keeping this answer a bit shorter. I'll edit my answer

Answer (score 0):

Given that the only "marker" is a number set in parentheses, marshalling the machinery of the `amsthm` package may constitute overkill. Using the machinery of the `enumitem` package may be more straightforward.

If you don't want the text of the theorems to be renderered in italics, delete `\itshape` from the `before` option. If you don't want hanging indentation, change `left=0pt` to `wide=0pt`.

[image]

```
\documentclass[11pt]{amsbook}
\usepackage{lipsum} % filler text

\usepackage{enumitem} % for \newlist and \setlist macros
\newlist{nitem}{enumerate}{1}
\setlist[nitem]{label = \upshape(\arabic*),
                ref   = \upshape\arabic*,
                resume,
                left  = 0pt,
                before= {\vspace{0.5\baselineskip}\item\itshape},
                after = {\vspace{0.5\baselineskip}}
               }

\begin{document}

\noindent\lipsum[1][1-3]

\begin{nitem}
This is a test of the emergency broadcasting system.
\end{nitem}
\noindent\lipsum[1][4-6]

\begin{nitem}
This is another test of the emergency broadcasting system. This is another test of the emergency broadcasting system.
\end{nitem}

\noindent\lipsum[1][7-9]

\begin{nitem} \label{item:yet_another}
This is yet another test of the emergency broadcasting system. This is yet another test of the emergency broadcasting system.
\end{nitem}

\noindent\lipsum[1][10-12]

\bigskip
A cross-reference to ``theorem'' \ref{item:yet_another}.

\end{document}
```

Comment: Ah, I may have been a bit vague here. This environment will not be the only kind of environment that will appear. There are also theorea, lemmas, definitions, etc. (all styled with a parenthesized number, but declared, too) in the text, all consecutively numbered. I think I could use your idea by making an environment that picks up the last value of equation, changes enumi to take the next value, and then formats it your way with the enumerate. Let's see if there is another idea, but yours will be helpful elsewhere. Thank you.